# Centralizer of the element $(12)$ in $S_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

From Artin's Algebra:
I'm looking to see if my solution is right.

> What is the centralizer of the element $(12)$ in $S_{5}$?

My solution:
We know that $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ is the permutation obtained from $\sigma$ by changing its entries according to $\tau$.

For example $(1234)[(12)(35)](1234)^{-1} = (1234)[(12)(35)](1432)=(1234)(1435)=(23)(45)$ and $(23)(45)$ is obtained from $(12)(35)$ by changing the labels $1, 2 , 3 , 4, 5$ according to the rule $(1234)$.

Using this we see that the centralizer $(12)$ in $S_{5}$ is $S_{2} \times S_{3}$ where here $S_{2}$ are the permutations of $1, 2$ and $S_{3}$ are the permutations of $3, 4, 5$.

Correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.